# can this spritz cookie dough be saved

Tags: baking

recipe was creamed butter, powdered sugar, flavorings and flour . dough is dry and crumbly not the usual consistency of spritz dough - should I try adding more butter ?

Comment: Hi sue. Can you post the actual recipe? I don't think anyone's going to be able to tell you if you need more of something if we don't know how much you started with.

Comment: No eggs?  Very few cookie recipes work without eggs, which add liquid and emulsifiers.  If that is the omission, you can probably add it, although the extra mixing will probably make them a little less tender then expected.

Comment: I agree with SAJ, this kind of cookie dough normally has egg in it, and it sounds like it needs more liquid.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto to eggs.  Otherwise, I would add water, not butter.

Comment: Spritz cookies shouldn't have water added -- they are supposed to be among the tenderest and fragilest of cookies, part of the reason they're extruded rather than rolled out. This answer could also use some expansion -- _why_ eggs? How much? What effect do you expect them to have?  How should they be incorporated?